# Layout issue when subscribed to popular tag

Tags: bug, tags, design, firefox

I noticed a minor layout issue if you are subscribed to a popular tag. If you hover over a tag it shows you a popup with the tag-wiki description and some other basic info. The "unsubscribe | rss" `span` is pushed down as a result of the "# followers, # questions" text having more characters than other tags.

[image]

Comment: Mine doesn't look like that on Chrome on the main question lists, what browser/sizing/area are you viewing on?

Comment: @Klors FF 41.0.2 with more than ample resolution. Tested on Chrome and it looks good so seems like a FF layout issue.

Comment: Yeah, just had a look and IE11 seems okay too

Comment: I just saw this similar question but it was closed:
http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253534/too-many-followers-and-questions-break-the-tag-popup-layout?rq=1

Comment: It's over a year old though, plenty could have changed to break it in the mean time :)

Comment: Might be worth noting the exact OS, resolution, zoom level, font scaling level, etc. for a reproducible case

Comment: Windows 7 Pro, FF 41.0.2 (I've never touched the default font settings), 100% zoom, and I don't know what font scaling is. The `#content` div on stack overflow is confined to `1000px` so any resolution above that should reproduce the issue.

Comment: This looks like yet another font metrics issue. Annoyingly, that means that its reproducibility will depend not only on your browser, OS and display settings, but also on the set of fonts you happen to have installed.

Comment: I'm on FF 40.0.2 and this is reproducible. Note that you need to subscribe to the tag to see the issue. The default "subscribe" link fits (barely), add 2 more characters ("unsubscribe") and everything hurts.

Comment: I almost got tricked into getting emails for [javascript].

Comment: Does it change if you maximise your browser window?

Comment: @MarkFitzgerald no the main #content div is fixed to 1000px so it does not change.